# Websphere MQ, receive large (100 MB) message

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I'm trying to read a 100 MB file from a Websphere MQ queue. File should contain approx. 800.000 records. But after a certain row number (usually around 90.000), I get only empty (or perhaps &#65533, depending on how I try to view the file).

I'm told the queue should allow 100 MB messages.

My code:

```
            var mqQueueManager = getMqQueueManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQ_QueueManager"]);
            var mqQueue = mqQueueManager.AccessQueue(mqReceiveQueueName,
                                                        MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

            MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            gmo.Options = MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT;

            for (int i = 0; i < maxMessagesToRead; i++)
            {
                var mqMessage = new MQMessage();
                mqQueue.Get(mqMessage, gmo);

                messageTexts.Add(mqMessage.ReadString(mqMessage.MessageLength));
            }
```

Something wrong with this code? Or is the error on the sending side?

Comment: Yes, MQ does allow message size of 100MB. Configuration changes in Queue Manager, Queue and Channel required for that. Have you done?

Comment: Please check MAXMSGL attribute. It defines maximum message size. This attribute exists on queue, queue manager and channel levels as @Shashi said

Comment: MQ settings appear correct. Is mqQueue.Get(mqMessage, gmo) correct or should I use mqQueue.Get(mqMessage, gmo, maxMsgSize) overload? Is mqMessage.ReadString(mqMessage.MessageLength) correct or should I use for example mqMessage.ReadFully(...)? Anything else worth trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what's being asked and I believe that is the root of the problem here.  While it is true that MQ can handle messages of up to 100MB in size, that isn't how the question reads.

> I'm trying to read a 100 MB file from a Websphere MQ queue. File
>   should contain approx. 800.000 records. But after a certain row number
>   (usually around 90.000)

Hidden in that single statement are references to:

- Files
- Queues
- Records
- Rows

I'm sure everyone you asked is responding as for queues, hence repeated assurances that MQ can handle 100MB messages.  But the code appears to be reassembling a **file** that's been split into one **record/row** per **message**.  That's a completely different use case.

Taking these one at a time, it is completely possible in MQ to pass 100MB messages back and forth.  Doing so requires every QMgr, channel and queue along that path to be configured up from the 4MB default for `MAXMSGL`.  Less obvious is that there must be sufficient log space to contain multiple 100MB transactions if using linear logs and/or the message is handled under syncpoint.  The default log extent counts and size do not anticipate 100MB messages.  Finally, the application needs to provision a sufficiently large buffer and make sure not to tell MQ to allow truncated messages.

This method of movign files over MQ is limited to files of under 100MB but has the distinct advantage of atomic operations - either you GET/PUT the whole file or none at all.  There are no missing parts, nothing out of order, etc.  This greatly simplifies the code.

The second possibility is that the code is reassembling a file that's been split into many messages. It seems doubtful that the code snippet posted actually wants to append multiple 100MB messages to each other so I'm assuming it is trying to reassemble a file from many messages.  (Up to 800,000 I believe.)  In this case the issue is how many messages can be in a single unit of work.  The code snippet omits any meaningful error handling so I assume syncpoint handling has been omitted as well.

Among the errors that crop up when reassembling a file are out-of-sequence messages and missing messages.  Even the simplest simple MQ-based file mover that uses multiple messages per file would need to use syncpoint to ensure the entire file is sent or received as a unit.  But MQ does not anticipate 800,000 messages in a single unit of work so you'd need to tune both the log extents ***and*** `MAXUMSGS` to do anything more than a trivial case.

Of course, moving files and guaranteeing their integrity when they are split into many messages is not trivial and by the time all the permutations are accounted for the result looks a lot like MQ Managed File Transfer.

Getting back to the question, if the file is being transported in a *single* message and the API option to truncate messages is not set, then there's nothing in the MQ API that would affect the message after some number of rows or message length.  In that case the only way to explain getting garbage past a certain point is that the sending app sent it.  (For example, allocated 100MB buffer, filled 50MB of it, then sent 100MB message.)

However, if the file is split into many messages as appears from the code, then the tuning mentioned above must be performed.  That included bumping `MAXUMSGS` to a value greater than 800,000 ([doc link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026790_.htm)) and ensuring that there's enough space in the Primary and Secondary log extents to hold a few large units of work.  See [Calculating the size of the log](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q018470_.htm) for details.

As an aside, you might also want to reset the `MQGMO` each time because as noted in the [Overview](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q096720_.htm) for that object, it is both input *and* output.

The modified code would look more like this:

```
            MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();

            for (int i = 0; i < maxMessagesToRead; i++)
            {
                var mqMessage = new MQMessage();
                gmo.Options = MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT;
                mqQueue.Get(mqMessage, gmo);
```

Comment: Yes it's a single message being passed. Seems the problem is on the sending side and not in the code to receive the message then (above). Thank's for explaining!